# XSLT works with Opera, Safari and Chrome but not with Firefox 13 and Internet Explorer 9

Tags: html, firefox, xslt, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

I've some problems with Internet Explorer 9 and Firefox 13. I'm building a Web Interface using HTML, XSL and XML, it works fine with Chrome, Opera and Safari without any changing, but it doesn't work with Firefox 13 and Internet Explorer 9. With Firefox there are some pages (not all) that can't load XML values, in Internet Explorer I'm not able to load css for html pages which use XSLT, but I can load all the parameters correctly.

Above you can find an example of a page that does not work (HTML,XML,XSL)

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname+"?id="+Math.random(),false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml=loadXMLDoc("sensorParameters.xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("sensorParameters.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
</head>
</html>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
          <title>Interface</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    (It continues, but it is not important...)
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sensorParameters.xsl"?>
<section1>
<section2>
          ......... some data
</section2>
<section3>
          ......... some data
</section3>
          .........
</section1>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Marco

Comment: Can you post a URL to a minimal but complete sample that fails with Firefox and explain in more detail what fails e.g. if you get an error, which one exactly?

Comment: You might like to look at Saxon-CE which hopefully would solve most of the problems of cross-browser compatibility for you.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Hi Martin, thanks for your reply. I can't post a URL because I'm working locally. What happens is that if I have a table that I want to fill with some values from an XML file, Firefox is not able to load them. However, if I use firebug to look at the source of the page, I see that firefox load correctly the parameters, but it is not able to show them.

Comment: your examples (even modified to test css) work for me in FF.  I would suggest adding an `<xsl:output method="html">`.  Since you are working locally, FF also gets very picky about allowing fragments from different base url's so watch out for that.

Answer (score 0):

As for the IE problem, I think one probable cause of the problem is your approach of using XSLT to create a complete HTML document with `html` root element, `head` section with `link` to a stylesheet, but then to try to include the XSLT result into a `div` element (where IE then probably ignores the `link`). To fix that you would need to change the approach and make sure you add `link` elements created by XSLT to the `head` of the HTML document you insert the XSLT transformation result into.